# Can someone read production week from this serial?

Tags: iphone, serial-number

The serial looks like this

a13038xxxxxxxxxx

I know that I have to look for 3rd digit for the year, and 4th and 5th for week of that year to get the week when my iphone was made.

Do I count the first letter or not? Or I start form the first digit after the letter 'a'?

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone 3GS model number is A1303, so I'm guessing that if you're looking at your serial number, it's somewhere with the model number appended to the beginning. To see just your serial number, go to Settings > General > About.

Once you have your serial number, the 3rd character will be production year, the 4th and 5th characters will make up the production week.

For additional info, check out ["iPhone Serial Number Secret (Decode Color, Size, Production Year and Week)"](http://www.mydigitallife.info/iphone-serial-number-secret-decode-color-size-production-year-and-week/) on My Digital Life.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is how a serial works as that is a 3GS Model number, but if you count it yourself...

The 3rd **character** is a 3 which suggests 2003 or 2013. As 2013 hasn't happened I would assume 2003, however no iPhones were made in 2003

The 3rd **number** is a 0 (suggests 2000 or 2010) no iPhones were made in 2000.

That is why I strongly think that this idea of a production date being included in a serial doesn't exist in this form.

The other reason is that my iPhone 4S serial only has 3 numbers in it and is in this format A38BBCDEFGF2, this is totaly out of sync with all possibe formulas on iPhone serial number production dates.

My 3GS has 881270*****

Under this principle the phone would have been made in 2011, I got the phone in late 2010 - it was a refurb, so I doubt that is the case.

Comment: 0 also mean 2010 :), but I am not sure if the first letter counts or not